# WMI \root\microsoft\windows\dhcp not returning any data

Tags: windows, active-directory, wmi

I use WBEMTEST.exe to test WMI on Windows Server 2012 R2.
DHCP feature on this windows is installed and DHCP Server have a scope.

[image: Image of DHCP Scope]

**Step 1 :** Open WBEMTEST.exe and connected to *"root\microsoft\windows\dhcp"* namespace.

[image: Image of namespace connected]

**Step 2 :** Sended this "SELECT * from PS_DhcpServerv4Scope" query.

[image: Image of query]

After all of this, WBEMTEST not returning any data of DHCP Server Scope.

[image: Image of result]

> I test all steps on Windows Server 2016 but WBEMTEST not returning any data too.

What was my mistake? Can anybody help me?

Comment: The result of the query itself is empty, what do you expect? It doesn't even have any properties in this context. Try to expand the content of the Class (demo in PS): `(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName <YOURSERVER> -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\DHCP -List | Where-Object Name -eq 'PS_DhcpServerv4Scope').Get() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty cmdletOutput`

Comment: Opps, yes. I test your command and PS gave some result. I try "DhcpServerv4Scope" in WBEM but not returning any data. What do i do?

Comment: What do you *want* to do? The object DhcpServerv4Scope is empty, so nothing is returned. But that class has some properties (which has some data). If you want to list those, click list, then open. There is no (known to me) WMI select command to list a classe's classes (and properties), so you have to use PS or VBS. Have a look at this article from the scripting guy: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee692770.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you able to resolve it and got result by running the WQL Query `Select * from PS_DhcpSerever4Scope`? I'm also facing the same issue, getting empty result.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/551202)